# Having trouble getting any cocoapods to work in Xcode 9.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a xcode project a few weeks ago and added GoogleMaps Pod with no issues. Now I am trying to add a logging framework to my project and cannot get any new pods I try to work. I tried SwiftyBeaver, Log4swift, and Willow. The pods all install but they fail on import (e.g. import Willow) in appdelegate.

I tried adding framework to embedded Binaries to no avail. Not sure if this is related to moving to Xcode 9.4.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your pod file?

Comment: Are you sure you are using workspace and not project file?

Comment: Yes, I am using xcworkspace to open project, Here is my podfile: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MapIt' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MapIt
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Willow', '~> 5.0'
end

Comment: having this issue too, upgraded to 9.0 target, not sure if that is the reason